# Wordpress Customiser & Sanitization

Tags: wordpress, sanitization

Hi folks i’m hoping someone can assist me. I’m learning WordPress Theme Development and i’m just at the point of adding options in the customiser. I’m not sure how to correctly deal with html in a text area. I want to make sure that the texture is sanitised and safe, but also allow it to output HTML. This is the function and code that i’m using.

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'fs_theme_footer', array(
'default' => '',
'type' => 'theme_mod',
'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
'transport' => '',
'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_textarea',
) );
$wp_customize->add_control( 'fs_theme_footer', array(
'type' => 'textarea',
'section' => 'fs_theme_footer',
'label' => __( 'Textarea Field', 'fluidstudio' ),
'description' => '',
) );
```

In my theme

```
<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'fs_theme_footer', '' ) ); ?>
```

I have tried different variations of escaping etc but i can’t seem to get the output to correctly display as html, instead the full html code shows on the front end.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses' function of WP, to sanitize the text field. Give it a try and let me know whether it helps...

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, so i tried what you suggested like so                      <?php echo wp_filter_nohtml_kses( get_theme_mod( 'fs_theme_footer', '' ) ); ?>     But unfortunately it makes no difference, it still out puts the html on the front end. Thanks